# Put third column of dataframe in next row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have dataframe which contains three columns like this:

```
id   no.  name
1A   32   ABC
4D   34   CFD
3B   32   DGA
```

and i want to shift the third column to consecutive next row like this:

```
1A   32
ABC
4D   34
CFD
3B   32
DGA
```

How this is possible in Python?

I tried via creating two dataframes one contains "id and no." and another one "name" and then merged them. But I did not like the output its not clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split out the `name` series into a new dataframe and manipulate the indices of the two resulting dataframes. Finally, use `concat` to combine them.

```
# split out dataframe of names
df_name = df.pop('name').to_frame('id')
df_name['no.'] = ''

# manipulate indices so they are non-overlapping
df_name.index = df_name.index * 2 + 1
df.index = df.index * 2

# concatenate two dataframes
res = pd.concat([df, df_name]).sort_index()
```

Result:

```
print(res)

    id no.
0   1A  32
1  ABC    
2   4D  34
3  CFD    
4   3B  32
5  DGA
```

Comment: That's good but I don't want any NaN to appear. Is something possible without NaN?

Comment: It's possible (see update), but not advisable as you now have a series of mixed types (integers and empty strings).

Comment: Do I need to create empty dataframe first because its giving df is not defined?

Comment: `df` is your input dataframe, as in your question. This is the only input for my logic. Everything else is derived.